# The assembly with display name 'VJSharpCodeProvider' failed to load

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I added an AjaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender to my ASP.Net 3.5 application. The web service lives in the same web application. Now I am getting this error when I hit F5/Debug in VS2008, and backing out the changes step-by-step so far have not revealed the cause yet.

I can't seem to get rid of the error. While the application starts up and I don't notice any issues once it is running.

```
BindingFailure was detected
Message: The assembly with display name 'VJSharpCodeProvider' failed to load in 
 the 'LoadFrom' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 4. The cause of the
 failure was:
 System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
'VJSharpCodeProvider, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
 PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system 
 cannot find the file specified.
 File name: 'VJSharpCodeProvider, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = VJSharpCodeProvider, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\
  v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: VJSharpCodeProvider, Version=2.0.0.0, 
  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a/VJSharpCodeProvider.DLL.
etc
```

Comment: id this being defined in your web.config?  I don't know if you need a reference to it in the web.config if it is being define in the same application.

Comment: I am not using JSharp, and it is not defined anywhere.

Comment: So is there a way to exclude it from the assembly?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So I think that this is a non-issue. The exception probably gets thrown all the time, but I had turned on "Break when an Exception is thrown" in Debug/Exceptions for all types there, to diagnose an unrelated problem. Since I unchecked the check boxes to their default state, I no longer see the binding problem.

Comment: this is a workaround. I used it and it works, but the reason can be found Inuyasha's answer

Comment: Where is that configuration located?

Comment: In VS2010, Debug --> Exceptions. Or try Ctrl+Alt+E. I found that if I clear the Managed Debugging Assistants Thrown checkbox, this issue goes away. And if I have the other checkboxes checked, it will still throw on error. I haven't done much more that a quick 30 second test though.

Answer (score 5):

We got this a few times here at work.  [Here's what we found.](http://blogs.msdn.com/pfedev/archive/2007/11/13/assemblyresolve-event-and-vjsharpcodeprovider.aspx)

Comment: Thanks - I did come across this post while I researched this error message.

Comment: Very good reading, +1 for that. But the post offers no solution.

Answer (score 4):

If the accepted solution doesn't work for you, try installing the VJSharp redistributable package.

32-bit: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18084

64-bit: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=15468

This got me past the error when none of the other solutions would work.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me after a BSOD on my machine. Clearing the AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/ folder did it for me, I guess the temp files got corrupted as a result of the crash.

Comment: Note that ASP.NET temp files under Windows 7/IIS7 are in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<Framework version>\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ Deleting the temp files did the trick for me too.

Answer (score 1):

I too have received the same error, but my solution was very different to all of the above.  In the web config I had a reference to an Assembly Binding such that it was older than the version I was trying to load eg.

```
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NLog" publicKeyToken="5120e14c03d0593c" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
```

and I was trying to install version 4.2.3.  I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was attempting to compile a BizTalk project in VS2010, and I got

> Could not load file or assembly 'VJSharpCodeProvider, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. An error relating to security occurred. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x8013150A)

None of the other answers in posted so far here worked - but doing [this](http://askesian.net/post/1356409661/vjsharpcodeproviderbuilderror) on the user for my BizTalkServices IIS site did. This is only on my local machine, not actual production.

Whie the wisdom of giving the user for an IIS site admin priveledges is certainly debatable, perhas this will offer a clue for finding the real problem for someone.

Comment: Hmm - sorry 'bout that @Arman. From memory, it was something like giving the Biztalk user full administrative privilege on the machine. A bit nasty, but like I saud this was only for local dev; it worked anyway in actual test environments.

Comment: I agree, the permissions might have been a reason. I had a similar issue: a library that used was trying to access protected directories.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, but for a different reason - I was referencing a C++/CLI DLL file.

After a couple of days of banging my head against a wall I downloaded and installed the [latest Visual C++](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328) and everything worked.

EDIT: After a couple of days of working with the project, I witnessed this error again in the Fusion logs. It appears that there was a different error hiding in the application: access denied or something like that. So after I fixed the error, this error didn't disappear from the logs, but wasn't breaking anything. So this error might be definitely misleading. Lesson learned: check your application for other errors, before trying to fix this one.