# The assembly with display name 'VJSharpCodeProvider' failed to load - Cloud App

Tags: model-view-controller, binding

I have MVC 2 project which I need to deploy to the cloud. I have a cloud app which has a web role associated with this mvc project. When trying to start a new instance of the cloud project in the dev fabric, I get the following error:

The assembly with display name `VJSharpCodeProvider` failed to load in the `LoadFrom` binding context of the AppDomain with ID 2. The cause of the failure was:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'VJSharpCodeProvider, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Can anybody please point me in the right direction on what the error means and how to resolve?

Answer (score -1):

I think this is not an issue - the exception probably gets thrown all the time.

See [answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511008/the-assembly-with-display-name-vjsharpcodeprovider-failed-to-load/1511161#1511161).